# Mapping Multiple Columns to same field of an Object which is part of an Array JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to map an array of Objects to a field. All the fields in that object are being mapped to columns with different name but similar structure. The response structure should be:

```
 "customers": [
    {
      "firstName": "string",
      "lastName": "string",
      "products": [
        {
            "description":"string",
            "amount": "string"
        },
        {
            "description":"string",
            "amount": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
```

Inside the products field, I have a list of product(description and amount). In DB, columns are stored like

```
product_des1,product_amt1,product_des2,product_amt2.....product_des30,product_amt30
```

. I need to map these two fields to the product(object). How should I approach to solve the problem using JPA annotations if possible?

For the reference:
**Customers.class**

```
@Entity
public class Customers implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @ElementCollection
    List<Products> products;

}
```

**Product.class**

```
@Embeddable
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Column(?)
    private String description;

    @Column(?)
    private String amount;

}
```

Comment: Just have a look into JPA spec.

Comment: @Zorglube I checked but did'nt find anything specific to this scenario.

Comment: So you have 1 table for both entities? And you can have a max of 30 products?

Comment: Search about  `JPA Attribute Converter`.

Comment: I would start by hunting down whoever designed the database.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Correct, and yes it has a max of 30 products.

Comment: In that case, Smutje's answer is the way to go. Though it would probably make more sense to redesign the database and set up a proper `@ManyToMany` relationship. This is currently not possible

Comment: @AlanHay Haha..even I had the same intention xD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside the products field, I have a list of product(description and amount). In DB, columns are stored like
>
> product_des1,product_amt1,product_des2,product_amt2.....product_des30,product_amt30

So your `Products` JPA entity should simply look like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class Products implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "product_des1")
    private String description1;

    @Column(name = "product_amt1")
    private String amount1;

    @Column(name = "product_des2")
    private String description2;

    @Column(name = "product_amt2")
    private String amount2;

   // ... repeat
}
```

if you don't want to do additional mapping between the DB and JPA entities (which I don't recommend - I try to keep JPA entities as exact representation of a DB row and map, if necessary, in Java and not between different technologies).

Comment: But using this way I'll be having several fields, it should be "description" and "amount". Moreover is it advisable to solve it programatically?

Comment: I *strongly* recommend to keep the database and the JPA entities equal, i.e. let the JPA entities reflect the DB 1:1 because having both a different technology (database vs. Java class) *and* representation (DB structure vs. object representation) is a guaranteed way to confusion and less maintainability because you have to keep multiple things in order when changing one or the other. I don't see any problem in having a proper object with a list of products as the "business" representation of your application and would do a mapping between both in a service, or simply adjust the database.

Comment: Oh okay , I'll try to keep my products class as suggested by you then later I'll manipulate while sending the response.